# Is there a way to use build variables in launchSettings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am invoking NUnit console runner manually like this:

```
"MyRunConfig": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "nunit3-console.exe",
  "commandLineArgs": "MyProject\\bin\\Debug\\MyProject.dll"
}
```

Problem is, I have to make a separate run configuration for Release build, as the output location is different. How do I do that? Can I somehow use `TargetPath` build property?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VS 2019 16.10.4, and I use the `$(OutDir)` and `$(ConfigurationName)` macros in my launchSettings.json. So your config could look like:

```
"MyRunConfig": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "nunit3-console.exe",
  "commandLineArgs": "MyProject\\$(OutDir)MyProject.dll"
}
```

Or using $(TargetPath) it would be:

```
"MyRunConfig": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "nunit3-console.exe",
  "commandLineArgs": "$(TargetPath)"
}
```

You can use any of the [Pre/Post-Build Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2019#macros). I typically go the "Edit Pre-build..." dialog (on the project properties "Build Events" page) and use its Macros button so I can see what they each resolve to.

I couldn't find this macro support documented anywhere by Microsoft, but it works for me in .NET 5.0 projects.

Answer (score -1):

I just upgraded to the latest version of VS2022 v17.2.0.
It does not work using macro in workingDirectory in launchsettings.json.
When I launch debug in VS, it throws an error that says the macro variable is not available.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).